how compatible is optimality theory with formal semantics
I know that several grammatical approaches are compatible with classical formal semantics other than mainstream Chomskyan ones (e.g. HPSG).
But how does Optimality Theory deal with lambdas and so forth?

What sort of interaction would you expect? OT is generally about phonology, and phonology doesn't overlap much with formal semantics.

Forgive me if I did not make that more clear. I'm talking OT syntax, ofc.

I believe Helen de Hoop, among others, has written on optimality theoretic semantics. It would be better if you read some more backgrounds like that and ask a more concrete and specific question if you don’t understand something or if you think there is an incompatibility.
